# My app keeps impersonating the user even when i put "false" in the web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, impersonation

Details of my app:
- ASP.NET MVC 3
- Windows Authentication mode
- IIS 6

So, in the web.config i put the impersonate to false, but when i try get the current user with `Environment.UserName` the app keeps getting the NETWORK SERVICE user. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the current user in an ASP.NET MVC application you should use the User.Identity.Name property:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var currentUser = User.Identity.Name;
    return Content("current user: " + currentUser);
}
```

`Environment.UserName` gives you the account under which the application pool executes.

Also make sure that in IIS you have disabled anonymous authentication in the properties of the virtual directory and left only Windows authentication checked.

Comment: In any class or only in views and controllers?

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni, anywhere you have access to `HttpContextBase` which is almost anywhere in an ASP.NET application. And in your service layers and models you shouldn't be trying to access ASP.NET artifacts. You should pass them as arguments to those methods.